# Context in resolve in NestJS Graphql Subscription is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, nestjs, nestjs-graphql

I just can't get my head around this issue. I read through the docs of [@nestjs/graphql](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/subscriptions#mutating-subscription-payloads), and even checked [type-graphql](https://typegraphql.com/docs/subscriptions.html) for comparison.

I have this Subscription that I need to get access to request's cookie in it, therefore I pass the request as context in the 'app.module' like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      playground: true,
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      autoSchemaFile,
      context: ({ req, res }) => ({req, res}),
    }),
    // ... other modules,
    ],
  providers: [PrismaService]
})
```

```
@Subscription(() => ResponseObjectType, {
    resolve: function (_, __, context) {
      condole.log(context) // gives undefined
      // here I need access to the Request object
      // return some response
      }
    })
    subscribeHere(@Context() ctx) {
      return this.pubsub.asyncIterator('subscribeHere')
    }
})
```

Also I publish to the subscription just as shown in the docs.
Help will be really appreciated.